# VueJS 2.0 - Can't hook a component on props update

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to force re-render component on update to be able to call `FB.XFBML.parse()`. However, no matter what I do I am not able to invoke any lifecycle hook `beforeUpdate`/`updated` when a property updated. (According to [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) it only listens for `data` updates which `props` obviously aren't).

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{myProp}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['myProp'],

    watch: {
       myprop: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
            console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
       }           
    },

    updated(){ // never invoked},

    beforeUpdate(){ // never invoked }

  }
</script>
```

I can see that the property `channel` changed when sending different values from a parent component.

Is there a hook to listen for `props` changes?

**Update**

As @chris suggested, I tried to `watch` my property but nothing changed. Then I realized that I've got a special case:

```
<template>
    <child :my-prop="myProp"></child>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      props: ['myProp']
   }
</script>
```

I am passing `myProp` that the parent component receives to the `child` component. Then the `watch: {myProp: ...}` is not working.

Comment: I believe mutation of the prop at the component level is not a desired behavior.  Props are meant to flow one way - parent to child.  An alternative way may be to create a computed property based on the prop and watch that one?  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: @dispake, I don't need to mutate `myProp`. I just need to know when it changed. When it a new `myProp` was sent from a "higher" (not only parent) component.

Comment: I would expect the prop to flow all the down to child and trigger watch in the child. Can you setup a jsfiddle demonstrating your usecase?

Comment: @Chris, yeah I will as it seems like kind of a bug...

Comment: @Chris I have created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Nobo/pen/ZyBVvo?editors=1010#0). The bad thing is I wasn't able to reproduce what's happening to me...

Comment: Yeah that's what I expected :) When things like this don't work it's usually something in your codebase. Are you using vue dev tools in Chrome? If not, definitely use them! Try going through your component tree and see if you can detect the prop changes in the parent first, then go down from there.

Comment: Your `prop` is `myProp` but you're watching `myprop` (lower-case).

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch):

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['channel'],

    watch: {
      channel(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Chris, thx for suggestion. I have updated my question accordingly.