# Watch props change on vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use watch for a props on a child component, but it's not working.

Here is my code :

```
props: {
    searchStore: {
        type: Object
    }
},
watch: {
    searchStore(newValue) {
        alert('yolo')
        console.log(newValue)
    }
```

And it's unfortunately not working

I've looked on this post and tried everything and nothing work : [VueJs 2.0 - how to listen for `props` changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584292/vuejs-2-0-how-to-listen-for-props-changes)

I checked my props with Vue Devtools and it's changing.

Thanks in advance to the community !

Comment: Are you sure you are using webpack/vue-cli type setup and not directly writing it in script file? That syntax is specific for such setup.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

based on that code, it *should* work, so the issue may be somewhere else. Can you post more code?

if you want to run immediately, you can use `immediate`. This is the syntax:

```
  watch: {
    searchStore: {
      immediate: true,
      deep: true,
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        
      }
    }
  },
```

The `deep: true` setting will deep-watch for a change within the object.

When you are updating parts of this object in the parent component, make sure you use Vue's `$set` function.

```
this.$set(this.searchStore, 'myKey', {price: 12.22});
```

further reading: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: thanks, the deep: true solved the problem. Still is it okay to let that in the code ? Would not trigger bug with time ?

Comment: glad that worked, I've updated the answer, if you have a chance, have a read-through of the `Change Detection Caveats` section of the link

Comment: ok thanks nice to know that, though i'm not planning on using it, the parents component is updating it, the child only read the data

Comment: sorry that it wasn't clear, you **need** to do it (use `$set`) in the parent component

Comment: In Vue 3, using `$set` is no longer necessary. You still need to use `deep` though.

Comment: @Giulio good to know that it's now automatic on vue 3 ! So this means all nested object inside another one that where not declared previously on `data`, vue 3 will automatically watch them now ?

Comment: @foufrix As I understand yes, objects shold be converted to proxies in 3.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that 'searchStore' wasn't changing?

Since its an object, vue is watching for a new reference of an object to be passed.

Meaning (will not trigger watch):

> roorSearchStore.a= newVal

will not trigger the watch  (since the reference didn't change).

You could watch deep like Daniel says,
Or do Object.assign like this:

> rootSearchStore = Object.assign  ({},roorSearchStore,{a:newVal}).

Or try to watch a timestamp of the changes in rootSearchStore .