# Watch route changes in Vue.js with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, watch

I'd like to detect changes in my URL in a Vue.js application using TypeScript. In JavaScript this can be done as follows:

```
watch: {
  '$route': {
     handler: 'onUrlChange',
     immediate: true,
     deep: true
   }
},

onUrlChange(newUrl){
   // Some action
}
```

How could I do the same in TypeScript?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator

It can be done like this:

```
   @Watch('$route', { immediate: true, deep: true })
   onUrlChange(newVal: any) {
      // Some action
    }
```

Comment: `newVal` type is `import { Route } from 'vue-router'`

Answer (score 5):

This was the way for me

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Route } from 'vue-router'

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  watch: {
    '$route': {
      handler: function(to: Route): void {
        // Do something here.
        console.log(to)
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
})

</script>
```

Comment: this is more JS-way for watch