# Vujs Iterating in component template not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Why can't I iterate inside the component template as follows?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="blog-post-demo">
      <blog-post :posts="posts"></blog-post>
    </div>
  <script>
    
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['posts'],
  template: `
    <div class="blog-post" v-for="post in posts">
      <h3> {{ post.title }}</h3>
      <button>Enlarge text</button>
      <div v-html="post.content"></div>
    </div>`,
})
new Vue({
  el   : '#blog-post-demo',
  data : {
    posts : [
      {id: 1, title : 'My Journey to Africa',    content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 2, title : 'My Journey to America',   content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 3, title : 'My Journey to Antartica', content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 4, title : 'My Journey to Asia',      content : 'I am the post'},
    ],
  }
})
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The one below works but I am confused as to why the one above doesn't work. Any explanation would help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My first Vue app</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="blog-post-demo">
      <blog-post v-for="post in posts" :post="post"></blog-post>
    </div>
  <script>
    
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['post'],
  template: `
    <div class="blog-post">
      <h3> {{ post.title }}</h3>
      <button>Enlarge text</button>
      <div v-html="post.content"></div>
    </div>`,
})
new Vue({
  el   : '#blog-post-demo',
  data : {
    posts : [
      {id: 1, title : 'My Journey to Africa',    content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 2, title : 'My Journey to America',   content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 3, title : 'My Journey to Antartica', content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 4, title : 'My Journey to Asia',      content : 'I am the post'},
    ],
  }
})
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait, which one works and which one doesn't?

Comment: The one above doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (and the edit)

Comment: props init problem, try `watch` it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584292/vuejs-2-0-how-to-listen-for-props-changes

Comment: @王仁宏 definitely not a props problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot have a repeated element as your template root.

If you use a development version of Vue.js, you would see...

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
>
> Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements.

Change your component's template to

```js
template: `<div><div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">...</div></div>`
```

### Demo

```js
Vue.component('blog-post', {
  props: ['posts'],
  template: `<div>
    <div class="blog-post" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
      <h3> {{ post.title }}</h3>
      <button>Enlarge text</button>
      <div v-html="post.content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>`,
})
new Vue({
  el   : '#blog-post-demo',
  data : {
    posts : [
      {id: 1, title : 'My Journey to Africa',    content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 2, title : 'My Journey to America',   content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 3, title : 'My Journey to Antartica', content : 'I am the post'},
      {id: 4, title : 'My Journey to Asia',      content : 'I am the post'},
    ],
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="blog-post-demo">
  <blog-post :posts="posts"></blog-post>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil! I have wrapped it in a the specified parent div. Where in the docs is this topic mentioned? I feel like I missed this part.

Comment: Not sure if it's in the docs but the error message you get is pretty clear

Comment: I will have to use development version then, to get these errors

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

"Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements."

A template can only have on root element, you can wrap your component in a DIV tag if needed but in this simple case I actually think that your second example is more elegant and conforms to the single responsibility principle for that component.

More information can be found within the VueJS official documentation:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element

Comment: I like the recommendation you pointed out about the single responsibility. I think this is a valuable piece of info as I am learning more about front end dev.

Comment: if the v-for is on the component I am assuming the single root element would be `id="blog-post-demo"` no?