# Pass props instantaneously to a child component in vue 3 by calling a function that creates a modal

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a problem with a vue component that handles model changes.

In the parent component I have something like this:

```vue
<div v-for="role in roles">
    Start date: {{ role.start_date) }}
    <button @click="handleSelectRoleToEdit($event, role)" id="start_date"</button>
</div>

<edit-role
    :role="selectedRole"
    :editField="editField"
    ref="ToEditRole"
    >
</edit-role>
```

where `handleSelectRoleToEdit` is

```javascript
handleSelectRoleToEdit(event, role) {
    this.selectedRole = role;
    this.$refs.ToEditRole.editRoleModal()
    this.editField = event.currentTarget.id
}
```

This piece of code should take the current item and pass it to the child component `<edit-role>`. Inside the child component there is

```vue
props: [
    "role", 
    "editField"
]

...

editRoleModal() {
    this.modal_edit_role = new Modal(document.getElementById('edit_roleModal'), {})
    this.modal_edit_role.show()
    console.log(this.role)
}
```

The modal is successfully created and opened, but `console.log(this.role)` returns `Proxy {}`.
If I edit the fields (so I call another function), everything is fine, because `this.role` becomes available.

However I need `this.role` to be available as soon as the modal is created.

How can I solve this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please review carefully, specially "suggested edit" queue. Look at the post in a whole: stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30274348, stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30261069, https://… and many more! For example, the first wasn't an answer at all, so the edit is not an improvement

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this suits your needs, but instead of using `$refs` you could [set a watcher for the prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584292/how-to-listen-for-props-changes) `role` in the child component. This ensures that the function is executed when the data is available.