# How to dynamically add data to chart js line graph on vue upon form submission?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3

I am having trouble dynamically adding data into my line chart. I plan for the line chart to be updated with new data every time the user submits a form with new data. Currently, I am able to push new data into the datasets array in App.vue's data function, but the chart would not generate the new data. It works if I manually type new data into the dataset array which confuses me even more. What should I do to fix it?

App.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <form>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-6">
          <label class="form-label">Score</label>
          <input type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control" id="score"
              name="score" placeholder="Score in %" v-model='score' />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 form-check col-6">
          <label class="form-label">Exam Type</label>
          <select class="form-select form-select"
              aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="examType"
              v-model='examType'>
              <option value="CA1">CA1</option>
              <option value="SA1">SA1</option>
              <option value="CA2">CA2</option>
              <option value="SA2">SA2</option>
          </select>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Subject</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject"
              placeholder="" v-model='subject' />
      </div>
  </div>

   <div class="modal-footer d-block">

      <button type="submit" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          class="btn btn-warning float-end" @click="addResult">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </form>
<div>
 <ChartTest :data="data" :title='title' />
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    import ChartTest from "../components/ProgressPage/ChartTest.vue";
    export default {
        name: "Progress",
        components: {
            ChartTest
    },
        
        data() {
            return {
                score: '',
                examType: '',
                subject: '',
                existingSubjects: [],
                colors: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#c45850"],
                title: '',
                data: {
                    labels: ['CA1', 'SA1', 'CA2', 'SA2'],
                    datasets: [
                              //dynamically add data here
                    ]
                },

            }
        },
    methods: {
            addResult() {
             
                let count = this.existingSubjects.length
             
                if (!this.existingSubjects.includes(this.subject)) {
                    this.existingSubjects.push(this.subject)
                    console.log(this.subject)
                    const newData = {
                        data: [this.score,54,43],
                        label: this.subject,
                        borderColor: this.colors[count],
                        fill: false
                    }
                    this.data.datasets.push(newData)
                    console.log( this.data.datasets)

                } else {
                    //TBC
                }
            


            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

ChartTest.vue

```
<template>
    <canvas id="progress-chart" width="600" height="450"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
    import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
    export default {
        name: 'ChartTest',
        props: {
            data: Object,
            title: String

        },
        mounted() {
            new Chart(document.getElementById("progress-chart"), {
                type: 'line',
                data: this.data,
                options: {
                    plugins: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: this.title
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {

                        y: {
                            display: true,
                            stacked: true,
                            max: 0,
                            min: 100,
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Your Score (%)'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a reasonable solution here is to observe props change in ChartTest component. Firstly, create chart instance `(const chart = new Chart(....))`. Every time chart data changes, you should call `chart.update()` to update the chart. 
 
 Follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584292/how-to-listen-for-props-changes) to know how to observe props change .

Comment: Is there a way for the page not to reload when i call the update chart function?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ChartJs, but I think updating the chart should not force the page to reload.